# iOS 10 , Xcode8 suddenly turns view backgroundColor to white / clear?

Tags: xcode, swift3, background-color, ios10

my app is behaving strangely. I think that it might have something to do with swift 3 and iOS 10 because until then it worked perfectly and I haven't touched the code of the things that changed.

So the problem is that I've set a backgroundColor in InterfaceBuilder to orange, I can see the color set on the view in my Storyboard, but when I run the app it just is white/clear (I have a white background)

the same thing happened to a subclass of a button, when its toggled OFF it should have a grey-ish color, now its just white.

I tripple checked if I'm not changing anything in the code, didn't find nothing.

Did something similar happened to you?
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, after updating to xcode 8.0

try resetting the constrains and add those again to the particular view

Comment: I have just found the solution!! It actually has to do something with constraints! I found out that I was using view.layer.setCornerradius = self.frame.size.width/2 ! And I'm using Autolayout everywhere